# How do i use this class in the main function? Dictionaries and indexers (Collections)

Tags: c#, class, collections, dictionary

I am trying to add entries in dictionary array list but i don't know which arguments to set in the People Class in the main function.

```
public class People : DictionaryBase
{
    public void Add(Person newPerson)
    {
        Dictionary.Add(newPerson.Name, newPerson);
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        Dictionary.Remove(name);
    }

    public Person this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Person)Dictionary[name];
        }
        set
        {
            Dictionary[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

using this seem to give me error

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
People peop = new People();
peop.Add("Josh", new Person("Josh"));
}
```

Error   2   No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments

Comment: you have to pass the parameters which you have defined in the overloaded Add method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `peop.Add("Josh", new Person("Josh"));`

should be this

```
   var josh = new Person() // parameterless constructor.
   {
        Name = "Josh" //Setter for name.
   };
   peop.Add(josh);//adds person to dictionary.
```

The class `People` has the method Add which only takes one argument: a Person object.  The Add on the people class method will take care of adding the it to the dictionary for you and supplying both the name (string) argument and the Person argument.

Your `Person` class only has a parameterless constructor, which means that you need to set your Name in the setter.  You can do this when you instantiate the object like above.

Comment: I get this error: Error 1 'ProjectName.Person' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 1):

For your design this would solve the problem:

```
    public class People : DictionaryBase
    {
        public void Add(string key, Person newPerson)
        {
            Dictionary.Add(key , newPerson);
        }

        public void Remove(string name)
        {
            Dictionary.Remove(name);
        }

        public Person this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                return (Person)Dictionary[name];
            }
            set
            {
                Dictionary[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return age;
            }
            set
            {
                age = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And in Main:

```
People peop = new People();
peop.Add("Josh", new Person() { Name = "Josh" });
```